# Listen to keystrokes if window is not on top

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent

Alright so I have a JFrame that I have a KeyListener added to, and I set the focusable equal to true. There is no problem with the KeyListener but it only listens to keys if the window is on top. What I'm trying to do is listen to the key strokes if the window is not on top. Basically, I'm trying to make a program that executes the code when the user presses F10 and stops executing the code when the user presses F10 again. The window shouldn't have to be on top for this program to work, meaning that if I press F10 and the JFrame is not on top, it will still execute. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to put the same KeyListener on the different frames? You may want to look into KeyBindings instead of KeyListener. KeyListener if a low-level interface while KeyBindings is OO.

Comment: Could you maybe send me an example of KeyBindings? I've already researched a bit on it but I feel like you might know a very simple tutorial on it. Thanks.

Comment: Google is your friend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html The main idea is that you separate the action (do something) from what triggers the action (in this case a KeyStroke)

Comment: Josh, if u find the answer, please post it, i have been wondering how to do that for a while...

Comment: I've been doing some research and I read the scenerios when I would want to use KeyBinding and I'm not sure this is what I want? Basically I want my program to work when the user presses keys on their keyboard regardless of whether or not the JFrame is on top or not. Do KeyBindings work in this case?

Comment: @JoshM Are you talking about other JFrame that you control that are on top? or are you talking about other programs that are on top? In the first case, it can be done, in the latter, it is not possible in Java (or at least the JVM does not provide this natively)

Comment: Sounds like a key logger.  What application feature does this provide to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Key Bindings/KeyListeners/any pure Java application will not work as the application must be on top for these to work.

You're looking for a keyboard hook, and Java by itself cannot do this. You'll have to use either JNI, JNA that are linked to a native app such as a C/C++ app, or easier still link Java to a scripting utility such as AutoIt (if Windows, or a similar utility if not). Note that any and all of these solutions *must* be platform specific.

Comment: Could you maybe redirect me to a link that'll help me please?

Comment: @Josh: You can find links and information about all these suggestions same as I would via Google. I'd recommend avoiding JNI unless your C/C++ coding skills are very good.

Comment: So, I can use AutoIt and it's strictly Java-based right? (You only need to know Java to program with it)

Comment: @Josh: No, AutoIt is strictly *Windows*-based. It's a programming language in its own right, based on Basic syntax, and without threading, OOPs, or other goodies that Java has. I have used it in conjunction with my Java programs quite a bit actually. I have had Java and AutoIt communicate via sockets (input and output streams). Lately though, I've been moving away from using it and moving more towards Java-JNA when I want to make OS-specific calls.

Comment: So should I be using the JNA?

Comment: You could, but you'd still need to write a bit of c code for the hook. For a key hook, I'd use autoit (if Windows). I'm using JNA to activate and control non-Java programs.